# How can I transform a sequences by mapping?

Tags: expl3

In Lisps, I can usually say

```lisp
(map some-function [some list here])
```

and this will be the same as

```lisp
[(some-function some) (some-function list) (some-function here)]
```

Note that I'm giving `map` a sequence and it's giving me a sequence back.

How can I get the same convenience from expl3? For example, I want to be able to say

```
\seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { one, two, etc. } { , }
\seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { mapping(##1) }
```

and have

```
\seq_show:N \l_tmpa_seq
{mapping(one)}
{mapping(two)}
{mapping(etc.)}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { , } { one, two, etc. }
\seq_set_map:NNn \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_seq { mapping(#1) }
\seq_show:N \l_tmpa_seq
```

Comment: Well, that was much easier than I thought. I guess I've just never seen this function. Thanks!

Comment: Beware that, for technical reasons, `\seq_set_map:NNn` performs full expansion on the third argument, so `\exp_not:n { mapping(#1) }` is possibly useful.

Comment: @egreg  I was thinking just now about that. In any case, why is it not returned with `\exp_not:n` by default? Any clear downside at first sight=

Comment: @Manuel I can think to cases where this wouldn't be desirable.

Comment: @egreg If `\seq_set_map:NNn` fully expands its third argument, why is it not named `\seq_set_map:NNx` then?

Comment: @HenriMenke (May be… ) That would mean that it expands the argument before passing it to a function, which might not be the case here (see for instance `\str_if_eq_x:nnTF` it's not `\str_if_eq:xxTF`). But for me what you proposed is what seemed correct.

Comment: @HenriMenke Ask the team! ;-)